# UIFont fontWithDescriptor:size: doesn't keep custom attribute

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uifont

I'm working with iOS 7 new font APIs.

I'm trying to add a custom attribute to a font attributes.
I can generate a `UIFontDescriptor` with this new attribute, but when I create a new font with it, the custom attribute is lost.

Here is the `UIFont` category method I use :

```
- (UIFont*)fontWithCustomAttribute:(id)myNewAttribute
{
    UIFontDescriptor *newFontDescriptor = 
        [self.fontDescriptor fontDescriptorByAddingAttributes:
              [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myNewAttribute
                                          forKey:@"NewAttribute"]];

    return [UIFont fontWithDescriptor:newFontDescriptor size:0];
}
```

`newFontDescriptor` does include `myNewAttribute`, but not the descriptor of the returned font.

Is there a way to have custom attributes in a `UIFontDescriptor` and preserve them when creating a font ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible, You can write you own category class and inside that pass your string and write the logic inside your category class. So whenever you send string to the method of your category class, it will extend the functionality and on the basis of that you will get the desired output. For example below is the code written in the category class. just import the category class in your contoller class and call these below method and pass your string:-

```
-(NSString*)getFontString:(NSString*)font
    NSString *str=font;
    NSMutableAttributedString *string = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:str];
    [string addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor redColor] range:NSMakeRange(0,string.length)];
    [text setEnabled:YES];
    [text setAttributedText:string];
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably no font is matched by your custom attributes (in `fontWithDescriptor:size:`), so they're getting lost because the font that is returned doesn't have them.

This code works fine when you replace:

```
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:myNewAttribute
                                      forKey:@"NewAttribute"]];
```

with e.g.:

```
@{UIFontDescriptorFamilyAttribute : @"Georgia"}
```

So the problem definitely lies with your custom attributes.

Comment: I understand your answer, but my need is not to add a well-known attribute such as Family, Size, Name, Traits, etc.  

It's more like adding a personal attribute, such as an NSDate for example, to be stored along the UIFont attributes and used later in my code.  

Maybe it's not the right way to do it because the UIFontDescriptor is not meant to be a generic data container.

Comment: Oh, then I think that UIFontDescriptor is the wrong way to do it. Should your personal attribute be associated with a font or maybe a string?